# Apache cordova iOS Icon not deploying

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have an Apache Cordova app developed in Visual Studio.

I have used a very basic icon

```
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" />
```

This works for Android, but iOS is using the standard cordova icon. From the docs, this should work. I then tried adding in a platform specific load for iOS platform like so

```
<platform name="ios">
 <!--iOS 8.0+ 
 iPhone 6 Plus-->  
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="180" height="180" />
 <!--iOS 7.0+ 
 iPhone / iPod Touch-->  
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="120" height="120" />
 <!--iPad--> 
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="152" height="152" />
 <!--iOS 6.1 
 Spotlight Icon--> 
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="80" height="80" />
 <!--iPhone / iPod Touch--> 
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="114" height="114" />
 <!--iPad--> 
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="144" height="144" />
 <!--iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon--> 
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="58" height="58" />
 <!--iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon--> 
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="res/icons/myicon.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>
```

But still no luck. Any pointers? The initial icon code works for Android

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was some transparency or something in the icon itself that prevented it being used for an iOS icon.